# How to add switchable items in one row of the RecyclerView?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

**Trying to Accomplish**

I'm trying to make a recipes section and I want to add a feature where the user can  swipe to change the item,

Example. Instead of chicken you can use beef, when the user first shows the activity it will show chicken but if the user swipes it will change to beef.

My problem is that it does not read the switchable items. I'm not sure how to read childs of a recyclerView

[image]

[image]

**My Code**

*Constructor*

public class IngredientsModel {

```
private String itemID, name;
private int item;

public IngredientsModel(){}

public IngredientsModel(String itemID, String name, int item) {
    this.itemID = itemID;
    this.name = name;
    this.item = item;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getItemID() {
    return itemID;
}

public void setItemID(String itemID) {
    this.itemID = itemID;
}

public int getItem() {
    return item;
}

public void setItem(int item) {
    this.item = item;
}
}
```

*My Adapter*

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<IngredientsModel> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<IngredientsModel>().setQuery(ingredientsQuery, IngredientsModel.class).build();
    ingredientsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<IngredientsModel, IngredientsHolder>(options) {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public IngredientsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.row_ingredients, parent, false);

            return new IngredientsHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final IngredientsHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final IngredientsModel model) {



        }
    };
```

My adapter is empty because I tried something using database listeners and I realized that it was impossible to do it with that.

Comment: Make every row switchable, starts with your `row_ingredients.xml`. Take a look at `ViewPager`. You might wanna put `ViewPager` in every row and make it be able to swipe in Adapter.

Comment: not a good idea. I would have to create a new fragment for each ingredient. I have no problem with the swiping or changing I just cant seem to get it to read the data I have.

Comment: What you need to do is to retrieve the id of each items along with their picture you wanted to use, then add all to viewpager. If you are quite interested in my answer, i can provide such solution. This is sample app i have developed that implemented the solution. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.project.android.chefcook